# Algebraization of Bayesian networks?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, pr.probability, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

The algebraization of classical propositional logic is Boolean algebra.

Bayesian networks are a generalization of classical propositional logic with probability truth-values.

What is the corresponding algebraic form of Bayesian networks?  Or at least outline how such an algebra would look like?  I seem to be at a loss as to how to begin...

Answer (score 11):

A bayesian network corresponds to an *independence (algebraic) variety* and hence to a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{R}$.
You can start from

> Garcia, Luis David, Michael Stillman, and Bernd Sturmfels. "Algebraic
>   geometry of Bayesian networks." Journal of Symbolic Computation 39.3-4
>   (2005): 331-355.